# In ruby how can i convert an array with multiple elements into a hash

Tags: ruby

Hello new to ruby but so far this is what I have.

```
test_array = []
test_hash = {}
string = "intended key"
variable = "intended hash value"

test_array += [string,variable,true]
```

test-array should now return ["intended key","intended hash value",true]
Other guides had me attempt something like this with little success

```
test_hash[string] << test_array
```

Ultimately I want to convert my updated array into a hash formatted like so

```
test_hash = {"intended key" => "intended hash value",true}
```

help much appreciated!

Comment: `{"intended key" => "intended hash value", true}` isn't a valid hash. Is `true` a key or a value? What's it associated with?

Comment: true ideally would be a value. From what Ive learned a hash consist of Key-value pair.  So am I right to assume a hash key with multiple  related values is impossible?That may be were my trouble is comming from.

Comment: Values can be arrays so `{"intended key" => [ "intended hash value", true ]}` is possible.

Comment: The `<<` operator is to append something to something that already exists. Now you're trying to add your array to the thing in the hash at index `string`. However that thing, which is the result of `test_hash[string]` is `nil` because there's nothing there yet. So you're trying to append something to nil, which doesn't work. You're probably looking for the `=` operator. The basic Hash documentation would surely be useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

As Ryan mentioned in his comment, `test_hash = {"intended key" => "intended hash value",true}` is not a valid hash, and as you mentioned in your comment, you might be confused as to what values a hash can have.

From the ruby doc [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D)

> A Hash is a dictionary-like collection of unique keys and their
>   values. Also called associative arrays, they are similar to Arrays,
>   but where an Array uses integers as its index, a Hash allows you to
>   use any object type.

The value can be any object, but `"intended hash value",true` is not a valid object.  You could do

```
test_array = [variable,true]
test_hash[string] = test_array

puts test_hash  
=> {"intended key"=>["intended hash value", true]}
```

but it's not clear what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Your Hash format is wrong. I don't know what you want to do exactly. but you can go with the below example. I am sure It would be helpful.

```
string1 = "intended key"
variable1 = "intended hash value"
string2 = "boolean value"
variable2 = true

test_array1 = []
test_array2 = []
test_array1.push(string1,string2)
test_array2.push(variable1,variable2)
final_test_array = test_array1.zip(test_array2)
test_hash = Hash[final_test_array]
```

Final Output:

```
{"intended key"=>"intended hash value", "boolean value"=>true}
```